# PostgeSQL выборка за текущую минуту.

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

С PostgreSQL опыта у меня практически никакого. Никак не могу понять как сделать выборку где значение поля попадает в интервал за текущую минуту.
Понимаю что нужно NOW() и BETWEEN использовать, но как "собрать" строки <start> и <end> для BETWEEN не догоняю.

```
SELECT a.*, u.* FROM activities AS a, users AS u WHERE a.user_id=u.id AND a.start_dt BETWEEN <start> AND <END>
```

Собственно вопрос в том, как "собрать" строки ).
Т.е. если NOW() вернёт 2014-01-04 20:01:32, то должно быть

```
BETWEEN 2014-01-04 20:01:00 AND 2014-01-04 20:01:59
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*, u.* FROM activities AS a, users AS u WHERE a.user_id=u.id AND a.start_dt BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 minute' AND NOW()
```

Comment: Всё таки могу предположить, что часть активностей в этот список не попадут.
Хотелось бы именно от нулевой секунды до 59-й

Comment: @dimka3210 тогда используйтен функцию date_trunc ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC )

Comment: Короче проще всего это всё сделать на стороне php. Спасибо за помощь.